# How to get the index of sorted timestamps?

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, timestamp

I have a text file that contains the following:

```
n 1 id 10 12:17:32 type 6 is transitioning
n 2 id 10 12:16:12 type 5 is active
n 2 id 10 12:18:45 type 6 is transitioning
n 3 id 10 12:16:06 type 6 is transitioning
n 3 id 10 12:17:02 type 6 is transitioning
...
```

I need to sort these lines in Python by the timestamp. I can read line by line, collect all timestamps, then sort them using sorted(timestamps) but then I need to arrange the lines according to sorted timestamp. 
How to get the index of sorted timestamps? 
Is there some more elegant solution (I'm sure there is)?

```
import time 
nID = [] 
mID = [] 
ts = [] 
ntype = [] 
comm = [] 
with open('changes.txt') as fp: 
        while True: 
                line = fp.readline() 
                if not line: 
                        break 

                lx = line.split(' ') 
                nID.append(lx[1]) 
                mID.append(lx[3]) 
                ts.append(lx[4]) 
                ntype.append(lx[6]) 
                comm.append(lx[7:])
```

So, now I can use sorted(ts) to sort the timestamp, but I don't get the index of sorted timestamp values.

Comment: Show us the code you have and we might be able to recommend a more elegant solution or how to get the index in your case

Comment: Put your code in your question.